# iPhone Configuration Utility shows the old name of the app

Tags: windows, iphone

I am installing the ipa file that is passed by my colleague in iPhone Configuration Utility. Although, he has changed the name of the app, iPhone Configuration Utility still shows the old name of the app. But in his computer, it shows clearly the name of the app has been changed. How do I clean my iPhone Configuration Utility? Btw, I am using Windows.

Need some guidance. Any idea to solve this?

Comment: "the iphone app that is passed by my colleague" - What does this mean?

Comment: ipa file that my colleague passed...

Comment: "passed" where? And how exactly did he change the name of the installed app? Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling using the latest installer from Apple's site?

Comment: he passed the ipa file to me to run in my ipcu and then i can add to my ipad. He changed the name in the product name in xcode.. The same thing in my friend's IPCU shows correctly, which is with the correct name...